# Is my git branch strategy best practice?

Tags: git, gitflow, release, strategy, branch

We are a small software team with 6 members. We are working on different software projects in our company.
Before I joined the team no version control system was used. It was/is my task to reorganize the team and daily work to use a vcs (git with own Gitea server).

I'm now at that point where I have to find an appropriate branch strategy. I studied git flow, GitHub flow, etc. But none of them seem to fit my needs (or I don't understand them correctly).

So here is what I have in mind and this is what we are currently doing:

First, we have our `master` branch. Pushing is restricted. Changes are only allowed via pull requests. New features are implemented on branches named like `feature/new-function`.

I want to define milestones like **Release 1.3** with a bunch of issues/feature requests which should be completed to reach the milestone.

All these new features, fixes, etc. are merged into the `master` branch. When the milestone is reached, a new branch from `master` is created named `release/v1.3`.
After the branch is created, a release/tag **v1.3.0** is created. (Gitea actions workflow creates docker images and pushes them to a registry).
Now we can define a new milestone, for example **release 1.4**. New features are developed and merged into `master` when they are ready. When a milestone is reached, we can create a new release branch and release tag.

So far, so good. But now bug fixing/hot fixing:
Imagine we are working on **Release 1.5**. Meanwhile, a bug in version **1.3.0** and/or **1.4.0** is reported. How to deal with it?
My suggestion would be to create a new branch `bugfix/dumb-error` from the oldest release branch to be supported (i.e. `release/v1.3`), fix the bug, push and then merge this branch into all release branches which are the same or newer than the oldest supported version (`release/v1.3`, `release/1.4`) and of course into `master`, where currently work for **release 1.5** is happening.
After that, we can create new release tags **v1.3.1** and **v1.4.1** which now include the Bugfix. **Release 1.5** will contain the fix from the first release tag onwards.

Is this a strategy considered correct/best practice or are there any big drawbacks I don't see now?

Are there improvements I can make, or is my strategy complete nonsense and will give me a lot of headaches in the future? What are the alternatives?

Any suggestions/comments are welcome!

Comment: For a small software shop, the approach that you describe sounds ideal. The only critique I would offer is that feature branch names ought to include a ticket number, so you can tell what modifications are in scope for that feature branch, and so you can tell when the feature is done, that is, when the ticket has been closed out. Otherwise there is a tendency for feature scope to creep, so a feature branch will last for a little more calendar time than was originally envisioned for it.

Comment: @J_H The OP doesn’t mention using a “ticket system” so I don’t see how ticket numbers are relevant to the scope of this question.

Comment: @J_H thank you for your answer. Including the issue number is a good suggestion. Will think about it and test it.

Comment: @Guildenstern yes. Didn't mentioned it in first place. But I want to work with milestones and issues.

Comment: @Guildenstern, yes OP mentioned "Gitea server", which offers issue tracking.

Comment: Something like the Nvie Git Flow (which you're proposing) can be appropriate when you have to maintain multiple releases of the software, e.g. both an 1.x and 2.x branch. But is that really the case here? Lots of projects just have a single latest version instead, which simplifies development, especially if you control deployment. But that's a business decision.

Comment: @amon I think nvie gitflow (https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) seems way more complicated than what I described. Ye, I thought about having only one version to support. But in our company features are often getting deployed very early to customer machines. Meanwhile other customers stay on an older release an should also get Bugfixes, while newer version is "tested" in production on customer machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make sure that the `master` branch can be released at any time, so that the following conversation can happen:

> CEO: Is New feature X already done?
> You: Yes, it has been tested and merged.
> CEO: Good. I have a customer who needs that feature ASAP. Forget about what else we had planned for the next release, I need a new release tomorrow morning.
> You: No problem. We will start making the release now and then it will be done in Y hours.

If you can support that, then you are effectively doing Github-flow with an adaptation for providing bugfixes on older releases.

Note that there is a difference between being able to deploy multiple times a day and actually doing so. While GitHub-flow officially states that you should deploy as soon as something is merged to `master`, there can be very legitimate business and logistical reasons to deploy new versions with a lower frequency, even down to once every few months.

Comment: Great. Especially the assumed conversation. I expect to have conversions like this from time to time. So I thought about this. I guess with my approach I am able to create Pre-Releases like **1.5-beta** from master branch, where all (tested) features which are completed up on this point are included. Thank you for your thoughts on my strategy!

Answer (score 4):

This exact workflow I've successfully implemented for my projects.

There is a minor complication though: we use Maven and it implies that for each patch/bugfix a version defined in pom.xml file is updated. This complicates the merge of changes from older to newer releases - we have to "skip" version bump commits by using `git merge -s ours` command. Otherwise, it works perfectly well and achieves seamless propagation of bugfixes.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had same question some time ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109008/release-branch-process-how-to-merge-release-branches

The answer I got and accepted seems similar to your way how to do it:

> See also [Raymond Chen's series of blog posts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325) describing this same idea.  Note that this general plan, "go back in time and fix the bug and then merge the fix forward in time", works for *all the bug cases*, and doing the "cherry-pick back in time so that we can merge forward" technique works in *all the bug cases*.  The fix need only be merged in any commit that is a descendant of the bug, and does need to be merged in *every* release that is a descendant of the bug, and the fact that it is or is not merged tells you whether the bug is or is not fixed.